# Work-around for deploying any:any size class to ios7?

Tags: interface-builder, xcode6

I've created a very simple iphone app in xcode 6. I used the any:any size class. It looks fine when deployed to 5s devices with ios8. In 5s devices running 7.1, however, the app is sized for the smaller 4 and 4s devices with black bars at the top and bottom.

Is there a work-around for this? If not, then it seems like size classes (and IB?) are pretty unusable right now.

Answer (score 0):

I did same with you and found some way out.

I tried this way:

Use the `Launch Images Source` **Images.xcassets->Launch Image** instead of `Launch Screen File`.

Then the size class worked with iOS 7.1 4 inch iPhone.

So, I think the `LaunchScreen.xib` is not worked with iOS version before iOS8, but `size class` is OK.

Answer (score 0):

If your screen looks like this.

["with black bars at the top and bottom"](http://s21.postimg.org/wif58bok7/5_7_1.png)

add a launch image with dimension 640x1136 named Default-568h@2x.png in your project

clean and build project and you will get desired result